# Redis - Using SET or STRING for readonly list of objects

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm currently working on a C# application, where I have bunch of dictionaries in MemoryCache (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory).
Planning to move on Redis (stackexchange).
All this dictionaries are just list of objects (10 to 500 items per dict) that needs to be cached for a while.

My question is: what is the benefit of storing arraies in SETS instead of STRING, if I dont want to use any of SET's commands, like SPOP, SUNION and etc. Or is it a good practice anyway to store list of objects in STRING type as JSON for example.

Comment: It depends on how you will use these data

Comment: It's an API, so I just return them for Client use.

Comment: In that case, i.e. always return the whole list to client, you can simply serialize the list to a string, and save it in Redis. No need to use Redis SET or Redis LIST, in fact, with SET or LIST, it will cost more memory.

Comment: Thats the answer I wanted to hear, Thank you!